# Windows Form Design-Time Error

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, designer

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and I get the following error message when trying to open one of my Forms:

> Could not find endpoint element with
>   name 'WSHttpBinding_ICommon' and
>   contract 'CommonWCF.ICommon' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no endpoint
>   element matching this name could be
>   found in the client element.

And the following stack trace

> at
>   System.ComponentModel.ReflectPropertyDescriptor.SetValue(Object
>   component, Object value) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertyAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeAssignStatement
>   statement,
>   CodePropertyReferenceExpression
>   propertyReferenceEx, Boolean
>   reportError) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeAssignStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeAssignStatement
>   statement) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement)

And yet I do have the element suggested in my App.Config and everything works at run-time.  However, whenever I try to open the form I get this message, which is not too bad because I can ignore it, but when I do many of the controls (those with anchors on the right side and/or the bottom) are shifted and my grids automatically regain all the columns from their datasource which (the columns) I had previously removed.

Any suggestions/workarounds? Is this a Visual Studio 2008 bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you using the endpoint? Do you really need it there or can you only call on it during runtime? You can use the Component.DesignMode property to determine whether you are in design mode so you can prevent the calls to the endpoint being made. To fully debug your design time experience follow the instructions in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ytx0z24(VS.80).aspx) article.

Comment: Brilliant. This helped to find the code causing the problem.  It seems the moving controls and adding grid columns is a separate issue?

Answer (score 2):

There's another approach to debug the devenv process (visual studio) in design time, like stated
[here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/wsod.aspx)

This helped when opening form in design mode throws exception (i.e. shows error to user).

Here is a summary from that article:

1. Open a new Visual Studio instance.
2. Open any source file. This is required so that Visual Studio lets you attach to a process.
3. Attach the new Visual Studio instance to the first one. The Visual Studio process is called devenv.exe. You only need to attach to managed code.
4. Set Visual Studio to break on Common Language Runtime exceptions - Thrown and User-handled.
   Close the problematic form, and reopen it.

This should result in an exception caught inside your code in the second instance of Visual Studio!

Comment: This should be shouted from the rooftops!  In this situation it is by far the quickest and most direct path that I've come across for finding the precise location of the error.

Comment: Superb!  For those searching for the mentioned menu items: for attaching to the devenv.exe process from your second VisualStudio instance, it's Debug -> Attach to Process...; for your CLR exception settings it's (VS2017) Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings.

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
        {
            return;
        }
```

To check for Design Mode in both the Constructor if it does anything other than InitializeComponent() and the Load Method if it has one.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error once in a form that tried to make a database call during constructor initialization.

Unfortunately, Component.DesignMode doesn't get set until after the constructor finishes!